# Usar os dados obtidos no parse do meu Web Service para transformar em um gráfico no Android

Tags: android, web-service, parser, gráfico

Eu tenho um web service que me retorna alguns valores, por exemplo agora está dessa maneira a resposta do meu parse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O parse que eu fiz para obter os valores filtrados foi este:

```
    String valFormaOutros = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(0).getTextContent();

    String descForma = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(0).getTextContent();
    String valForma = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(1).getTextContent();
    String descForma1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(1).getTextContent();
    String valForma1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(2).getTextContent();
    String descForma2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(2).getTextContent();
    String valForma2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(3).getTextContent();
    String descForma3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(3).getTextContent();
    String valForma3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(4).getTextContent();
    String descForma4 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(4).getTextContent();
    String valForma4 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(5).getTextContent();
    String descForma5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRICAO").item(5).getTextContent();
    String valForma5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(6).getTextContent();


    FormasDePagamento.tvFormas.setText("Outros: "+ valFormaOutros+ "\n"+ descForma + ": " + valForma + "\n" + descForma1 + ": " + valForma1 + "\n" + descForma2 + ": " + valForma2 + "\n" + descForma3 + ": " + valForma3 + "\n" + descForma4 + ": " + valForma4 + "\n" + descForma5 + ": " + valForma5);
```

Assim ele me retorna estes valores do print acima..

Agora, eu gostaria de reaproveitar estes dados para formar um gráfico (pizza), para os meus clientes poderem ver com uma precisão maior os indicadores..
Alguém tem idéia do que pode ser feito, ou até mesmo, refeito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o HoloGraphLibrary. Nunca usei mas parece ser simples
https://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary

No github tem esse exemplo:

```
PieGraph pg = (PieGraph)findViewById(R.id.graph);
PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC00"));
slice.setValue(2);
pg.addSlice(slice);
slice = new PieSlice();
slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
slice.setValue(3);
pg.addSlice(slice);
slice = new PieSlice();
slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AA66CC"));
slice.setValue(8);
pg.addSlice(slice);
```